# UcanAccess:::4.0.2 Unexpected token: 164 Update Query

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I need to make a Jar to format phonenumbers from an Access Database and used UcanAccess for this, all Queries work fine, until I need to update the Database column with the formatted phonenumbers.

```
public void updatePhonenumberColumn()
{
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.phoneNumbers.size(); i++) {
            String SQL = "UPDATE [" + this.table + "] SET [" + this.phonenumberColumn + "]=" + this.phoneNumbers.get(i) + " WHERE [" + this.id + "]=" + i;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "\nErrorcode: " + e.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

I have tried using brackets as suggested in other posts, the formatted phonenumbers are stored in an ArrayList by myself and then I try to add with an update statement. If something is not clear I will try to provide further Information.

I have tried using ResultSet.next() and noticed that the while loop is left instantly, as if ResultSet would be empty, which is not possible since I use the exact same code earlier to append the phonenumbers to my ArrayList.

```
    public void updatePhonenumberColumn()
{
    String sql = "SELECT " + this.phonenumberColumn + " FROM " + this.table;

    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        this.resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println(this.resultSet.getFetchSize());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "\nErrorcode: " + e.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

Below the earlier Query to get  the phonenumbers out of the Access Database

```
    public void executeQueryPhoneNumber(String tableName, String columnName)
{
    this.actualColumn = columnName;
    this.phonenumberColumn = columnName;
    this.table = tableName;
    try {
        this.query = this.connection.createStatement();
        this.resultSet = query.executeQuery("SELECT " + this.phonenumberColumn + " FROM " + this.table);
        appendItems(this.phoneNumbers, this.resultSet);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "\nErrorCode: " + e.getErrorCode());
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any ideas very much

Answer (score 0):

"Unexpected token: 164" sounds like your phone numbers have spaces in them and your dynamic SQL is failing. You should use a *parameterized query*, something like this:

```java
String sql = "UPDATE [" + this.table + "] SET [" + this.phonenumberColumn + "]=? WHERE [" + this.id + "]=?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < this.phoneNumbers.size(); i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(1) = this.phoneNumbers.get(i);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2) = i;
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```